# How VM Name is resolved over the LAN Network?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have hosted a VM (Red Hat Linux) named test-vm on my Desktop machine (Windows) with a static IP address but I don't have any DNS entry for this static IP address.

Without having an entry in the client's host file, to my wonder the ping test-vm responds. How is this possible? How test-vm is resolved at other machines on our LAN Network without having a DNS entry for test-vm?

Regards,
Adil Khalil

Comment: If your VM runs samba, it will typically broadcast its name, so that windows-based resolvers can use it

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using vmware client in your windows desktop. In this case, the hostname is associated to your vmware virtual DNS. With a ping of broadcast in your network, your vmware virtual DNS is forwarding the ping to your VM Client.

Comment: I am using Oracle VirtualBox, my question is how exactly the test-vm is resolved by the other PCs on the network.

Comment: Are there any hosts file on your other PCs, which is doing the name resolution? Are there any services like NIS, LDAP on your test-vm are doing name broadcast?

Comment: No, there isn't any host file entry on other PCs, Neither NIS, LDAP services on my test-vm!!